# how to export all projects inside a group in gitlab

Tags: gitlab, migration, gitlab-api

we are migrating from self hosted gitlab to gitlab.com subscription. We have parent 28 group and under these groups there are multiple subgroups and projects.

I know I can export one group and it will export all the subgroups under it and then I can import it.

but documentation says to export/import single project at a time. I have almost 3000+ Projects and doing this things 3000+ time is not possible.

Can you please suggest me How can I export/import all the projects under a group regardless it is in a group or under someother subgroup in hierarchy ?

or is there any other way ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write scripts that interact with the GitLab API to perform the migration of groups/orgs, projects, branches, and merge requests. See the following [post on GitLab's forum](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/migration-of-projects-from-on-premise-gerrit-server-to-self-hosted-gitlab-server/33124) for guidance.

Comment: I have 2500 projects and most of the projects are under another subgroups .. I am clueless how to pass these paths/Urls to script for gitlab import/export API.

What I understood is ..

git project IDs
for loop for those ids which will use export API to to export the projects..
Please correct me if I am wrong ?

Comment: Yeah. You have the right idea. Break the problem into smaller, easier-to-solve problems. Is there a programming language that you are comfortable with?

Comment: I am using following script to extract the project IDs of a group and all subgroups under this group and then using those Ids to start the export..

curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: *******" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/groups/*****/projects?pagination=keyset&per_page=2000&include_subgroups=yes&order_by=id" | jq .[].id > project_id.txt
while read i; do
    curl -XPOST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: *********" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/${i}/export" | jq
done < project_id.txt

with tweak in curl with same script I check status of export. I have problem with download

Comment: When I try to use same logic to download exports then loop does not wait for curl command to finish and corrupts the downloads. Any suggestions for this ?

Comment: Could you update your original post with your code? It is unformatted when in the comments section and difficult to follow.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler option might be to "Migrate groups by direct transfer"
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/import/

> You can migrate GitLab groups:
>
> ```
> - From self-managed GitLab to GitLab.com.
> - From GitLab.com to self-managed GitLab.
> - From one self-managed GitLab instance to another.
> - Between groups in the same GitLab instance.
> ```